# org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [select

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jooq, jooq-sbt-plugin

I am developing **Spring Boot JOOQ Integration** example. I am using same DB schema from link: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx in my example.

I am looking to perform inner join for two tables, but I am not able to achieve this yet. Also

```
SELECT 
    t1.orderNumber,
    t1.status,
    SUM(quantityOrdered * priceEach) total --- How for this ??
FROM
    orders t1
INNER JOIN orderdetails t2 
    ON t1.orderNumber = t2.orderNumber
GROUP BY orderNumber;
```

Error:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [select `classicmodels`.`orders`.`orderNumber`, `classicmodels`.`orders`.`status` from `classicmodels`.`orders` as `or` join `classicmodels`.`orderdetails` as `o` on `or`.`orderNumber` = `o`.`orderNumber` group by `classicmodels`.`orders`.`orderNumber`]; Unknown column 'classicmodels.orders.orderNumber' in 'field list'
    at org.jooq_3.12.3.MYSQL.debug(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:2717) ~[jooq-3.12.3.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:755) ~[jooq-3.12.3.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:382) ~[jooq-3.12.3.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch(AbstractResultQuery.java:353) [jooq-3.12.3.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetch(SelectImpl.java:2693) [jooq-3.12.3.jar:na]
    at com.example.jooq.service.OrderService.findOrder(OrderService.java:39) [classes/:na]
    at com.example.jooq.controller.OrderDetailsController.findOrders(OrderDetailsController.java:32) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

Below query I am looking to convert to

```
SELECT 
    t1.orderNumber,
    t1.status,
    SUM(quantityOrdered * priceEach) total
FROM
    orders t1
INNER JOIN orderdetails t2 
    ON t1.orderNumber = t2.orderNumber
GROUP BY orderNumber;
```

OrderService

```
@Service
public class OrderService {
    Products p = PRODUCTS.as("p");
    Orderdetails o = ORDERDETAILS.as("o");
    Orders or = ORDERS.as("or");

    @Autowired
    private DSLContext dsl;

    public List<OrderDto> findOrder(){
        Result<Record2<Integer, String>> fetch = dsl.select(ORDERS.ORDERNUMBER, ORDERS.STATUS)
            .from(or)
            .innerJoin(o)
            .on(or.ORDERNUMBER.eq(o.ORDERNUMBER))
            .groupBy(ORDERS.ORDERNUMBER)
            .fetch();
        System.out.println(fetch);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fixing your existing query

The answer is in the exception, and in your code. You intended to write a query where you aliased all your tables, which you did, in your SQL version. Yet, in your jOOQ query, you're using both the `ORDERS` and the `o` table to dereference column names.

Here's your fixed query

```java
public List<OrderDto> findOrder(){
    Result<Record2<Integer, String>> fetch = 
     dsl.select(or.ORDERNUMBER, or.STATUS) // Fix here
        .from(or)
        .innerJoin(o)
        .on(or.ORDERNUMBER.eq(o.ORDERNUMBER))
        .groupBy(or.ORDERNUMBER) // Fix here
        .fetch();
    System.out.println(fetch);
    return null;
}
```

#### Summing data

The sum that you want to calculate can be written effortlessly, just the same way as you wrote it in SQL. Translate the query 1:1 to jOOQ:

```java
sum(o.QUANTITYORDERED.multiply(o.PRICEEACH))
```

This is assuming the following static import:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```